# Block some entries. MySql

Tags: mysql

I am newbie in MySql, thus i have very naive question.
I have some database (for example, about hotels). All users may read information about these hotels. Admins are allowed to change this information.
My question is the following: How to block some hotel entry during its modification? In other words if some admin send a query for modification data for hotel1 (it takes time 1-10 secs) all other admins should wait with their modifications of this hotel. Users should see only old information until modification will be complete.

Million Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it truly take only a few seconds?  Then use InnoDB and `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.  Within such a "transaction" use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to lock a row that you are about to `UPDATE` (and you need to do some other work before actually doing the update).

Wherever possible you should make transactions run as fast as possible.  Any locking mechanism blocks other things.

It may make sense to build a Stored Procedure that is given all the parameters for the admin action, and have the transaction inside it.  This can probably be performed in less than a second.  With such, it should not matter if the second admin is *blocked* until the action is finished.

For long actions, an extra table such as Balazs suggests, may be necessary.  It could be really bad to use InnoDB transactions for long running "locks".

Please take the time to study some database theory and study some of the suggestions given here.  Otherwise, you are likely to create bugs that will be intermittent (eg, only happens when 2 admins act 'simultaneously') and are hard to track down.

That leads to another thing... Log, in detail, what these actions see and do.

Another tip...  (This assumes the admin needs to read some info, make a decision, then take action.)  Do `SELECT(s)` outside the locked area, let the admin make the decision, then the transaction contains only the update (very fast).  But it also contains information from the `SELECT(s)` to verify that nothing else has changed.  And make it so that the `UPDATE` will fail if things are not still the way the `SELECT` found them.  Once in a while, the admin will get a cryptic message (that you built) saying that "the action could not be performed, start over".  The admin should go back to the `SELECT(s)` *because they will now have new values* (from the other admin's actions).

That tip is akin to what InnoDB transactions do.  Certain conflicts are best solved by forcing the application to start over.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a locking mechanism, You have several options.
For example you may create a new table where you track who is editing and what is being edited. This new table will have an **unique** key with the fields of "record_edited".

When an administrator starts to edit a hotel detail, you insert a row into this table, and if the result says duplicate entry, then there is somebody already having that record modifying, and tell the admin to wait a little.

If this query returns without error, you then allow the admin to proceed.

When the admin finished with the update on the hotel details, you then remove the "locking record" from the table, and update the hotel details in the database.

Example table for the locking mechanism:

```
CREATE TABLE `mod_lock` (
 `who_editing` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `record_edited` int(11) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `record_edited` (`record_edited`)
)
```

This method will allow multiple hotel details being edited, while "table lock" will not permit changes to the whole table for the hotel details until the admin finishes with one update.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to LOCK the table as described in documentation:

[lock tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)

You could also create a transaction (which also locks the table) and it is a smarter way to do it, specially if you do it through an application:

[transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Comment: Engine Innodb never locks a table not even when used transaction unless you mean row (record) locking that will happen using transactions